# How to Unit Test a Time-related State Machine Using Mockito in Java

Tags: java, mockito

I have written a class called `ErrorHandingFiniteStateMachine`, which basically does something like:

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/developers_guide_v3#RequestFrequencyHashes

Basically it has a function called `ErrorHandlingFiniteStateMachine.update()`, which will be called when the caller class receives an error. It will then update the error state, which depends on:

- how many errors it has received;
- how much time it has elapsed since last error;
- and of course, the last error state.

Now my questions are:

1. How to mock up the time elapsed in `mockito`, because the time can be very long, such as hours, and I definitely don't want to wait for several hours to finish a unit test.
2. Is there any standard tutorial or best practice to test a state machine with time-related features?

**EDIT**

As folks pointed out, I use `System.currentTimeMillis` to remember the current timestamp. But BTW, the unit test is not supposed to know so much detailed info about the implementation, right?

**MY SOLUTION**

I finally wrapped `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the `ErrorHandlingFiniteStateMachine.getCurrentTimestamp()`, and make it package-private (no modifier), so it's accessible in my `TestErrorHandlingFiniteStateMachine`. Then I used a `mockito` `spy` to mock the `ErrorHandlingFiniteStateMachine.getCurrentTimestamp()`

Comment: We can't see any of the code you're trying to test - which means we have no idea how you're getting the current time. Basically, that's the dependency you need to fake out. So if you're currently using `System.currentTimeMillis` or something like that, you need to stop - instead, have an interface representing a "current time service".

Comment: So basically, you are saying that, there is no way to test if we use `System.currentTimeMillis` or `new Date().getTime()`? In order to test it, we have to use a time service that can be both used in the real code and the unit test code? That sounds weird. I guess that's why I am asking if there is a way to fake the timing thing to kinda `shorten` the time we need to unit test it.

Comment: You're calling static methods or constructors - while they *can* be mocked with PowerMock and the like, it's a much better idea (IMO) to isolate the dependency in a `Clock` object - then you'd normally inject an implementation which could use `new Date()` between the scenes, but for testing you can pass in a clock you control.

Comment: @PeterLee As Jon pointed out, you can mock (or fake) the system clock in Java, regardless of how it's accessed from the code under test. Whether it calls `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `System.nanoTime()`, or the Time API available in Java 8, it can always be mocked by using a mocking tool that is capable enough. For Java, we have PowerMock (which can be used with Mockito), and JMockit (which I develop). Personally, I see the alternative of injecting a `Clock` dependency as overkill in most real-world cases; I prefer the simplicity of using the standard Java APIs.